Computing the norm of bounded operator on the space of summable sequences using unit vector basis
Let $X$ be a normed space and $L$ a bounded linear operator from the space of summable sequences $\ell_1$ to $X$, and let $e_i$ be a unit vector sequence in $\ell_1$, i.e. a sequence with $1$ in the $i$-th entry and zeros everywhere else.
I am trying to prove that $\|L\| = \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\|L(e_n)\|$.
Showing the inequality in one direction is obvious, but I have no clue how to show $\|L\| \leq \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\|L(e_n)\|$.

Let $(a_n) \in \ell^1$, then,
$$\begin{split}
\|L((a_n))\| &= \|L(\sum_n a_ne_n)\|\\
&\leq \sum_n |a_n|\|L(e_n)\|\\
&\leq \left(\sup_n \|L(e_n)\|\right)\left(\sum_n |a_n|\right)\\
&= \left(\sup_n \|L(e_n)\|\right)\|(a_n)\|_{\ell^1}
\end{split}$$
So $\|L\| \leq \left(\sup_n \|L(e_n)\|\right)$.

Maybe you should add a sentence about why if $a=(a_n)$ then $a=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_ne_n$ is indeed true. This is not hard, but not absolutely obvious.
